# Скачать файл с удаленного сервера PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap, android, ios, blackberry, javascript

Добрый день всем, у меня возникла вот такая проблема, не получается скачать файл с сервера, использую код с документации фонгеповской, код ниже:

```
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var uri = encodeURI("https://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/conf/telefon.gleb.txt");
  var filePath = "/"

  fileTransfer.download(uri, filePath, fail, win, true);

  function fail(error) {
       console.log("An error has occured error: "+error.code);
  }

  function win() {
       console.log("download complete");
  }
```

А выдает вот такую красоту когда пытаюсь скачать файл:

> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> D/FileTransfer(7589):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 08-09
> 13:00:30.981: D/FileTransfer(7589):
>   at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:416)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> D/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:102)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> D/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:186)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> D/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589): Error while
> downloading 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589):
> java.io.IOException: Error while
> downloading 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:454)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:102)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:186)
> 08-09 13:00:30.981:
> E/FileTransfer(7589):     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
> 08-09 13:00:31.321:
> D/CordovaLog(7589): download error
> source
> https://www.google.com/logos/2012/slalom_canoe-2012-sr.png
> 08-09 13:00:31.321:
> D/CordovaLog(7589):
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:
> Line 24 : download error source
> https://www.google.com/logos/2012/slalom_canoe-2012-sr.png
> 08-09 13:00:31.321: I/Web
> Console(7589): download error source
> https://www.google.com/logos/2012/slalom_canoe-2012-sr.png
> at
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:24
> 08-09 13:00:31.321:
> D/CordovaLog(7589): download error
> target this.jpg 08-09 13:00:31.321:
> D/CordovaLog(7589):
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:
> Line 25 : download error target
> this.jpg 08-09 13:00:31.321: I/Web
> Console(7589): download error target
> this.jpg at
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:25
> 08-09 13:00:31.331:
> D/CordovaLog(7589): upload error code3
> 08-09 13:00:31.331:
> D/CordovaLog(7589):
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:
> Line 26 : upload error code3 08-09
> 13:00:31.331: I/Web Console(7589):
> upload error code3 at
> file:///android_asset/www/index.html:26

Что я не так делаю что у меня такая ошибка? Ссылка верная, путь как бы то же, должно в корень скачать, что не так? Есть идеи?

Comment: На какой платформе пытаетесь использовать fileTransfer.download?

Comment: phonegap, я же указал в название вопроса

Comment: платформа - android / ios / blackberry ? (в вопросе указаны все три). На всех ошибка или на какой-то определенной ?

Comment: в моем случае я пишу под андроидом, на других пока еще не проверял.

Comment: Ну что? Разве никто не сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    url,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {},
    function(error) {}
);
```

Метод download() принимает только 4 параметра (у вас последний лишний) и работает только на iOS и Android. Эти условия выполняются?

Comment: все выполняется. только файл не скачивается.

Comment: Может попробуйте качать не в корень, а в какую-то пользовательскую директорию? По крайней мере отбросите вариант с запретом записи в корень.

Comment: что-то на подобии /mnt/sdcard/Android/ ? пробовал, все равно не скачивается...